# If  and  are two independent random variables and  and g(X)+ are independent then g(X) must be a constant almost surely.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables and $g$ be a measurable function. Assume that $X \, \bot \, g(X)+Y$. Does this imply that g(X) is almost surely constant?

My intuition is that this is true but I have been trying to prove this. It would be great if someone can give me some ideas. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Note that $X,g(X)+Y$ independent implies $g(X),g(X)+Y$ are independent and hence uncorrelated, i.e.

$$E[g(X)(g(X)+Y)]=E[g(X)]E[g(X)+Y]=(E[g(X)])^2+E[g(X)]E[Y].$$

On the other hand, since $X,Y$ are independent, we have $g(X),Y$ are independent and hence uncorrelated so

$$E[g(X)(g(X)+Y))]=E[g(X)^2]+E[g(X)]E[Y].$$

Comparing the two shows $$0=E[g(X)^2]-(E[g(X)])^2=\text{Var}(g(X)),$$

which shows $g(X)$ is a.s. constant.